# Unbalancing equal weights on a scale

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]If two equal weights are kept on a swing, is it possible to unbalance them by applying only a horizontal force on the swing in such a way  that the sawing  starts accelerating? If we look into it practically it might be possible but I can't see any force that unbalances the weights.

Assume friction, air resistance and all external forces except the applied force to be zero.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the geometry of the swing? How do you cause acceleration without applying a force?

Comment: the swing is symmetrical and that is the reason it is balanced in the first place. And a force is applied. By external force I meant friction, air resistance etc.